# How to find Example of Session 311 - Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments

Tags: xcode

Ｉ download wwdc10samplecode.dmg,but i can't find "breadcrumbs" about Example of Session 311 .
how I to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its right here
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

Comment: but I don't find Example of Session 311 . I only find video of Session 311